# Не могу получить содержимое title на кинопоиске C#

Tags: c#, парсер, htmlagilitypack

Здравствуйте, использую для HAP для парсинга определенных страниц. Вроде бы все работает нормально, в том числе и поиск по Кинопоиску, но вот работать непосредственно со страницей фильма что-то не получается

```
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { AllowAutoRedirect = true, AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate })
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/") })
    {
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument HD = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HD.LoadHtml(client.GetStringAsync("839219").Result);

        //ищем заголовок фильма
        var kinopoisk = HD.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//title");
        if (kinopoisk != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(kinopoisk.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

839219 - это id фильма на кинопоиске. Может кто-нибудь подсказать что я делаю не так? С другими сайтами подобного рода парсинг работает, а тут нет...

Comment: А client.GetStringAsync("839219").Result возвращает вам html страницу то? Сохраните её в файл, да откройте в браузере.

Comment: Я не очень знаю, что такое HAP. Но, судя по названию метода `GetStringAsync`, он должен выполняться асинхронно. В результате в метод `LoadHtml` может передаваться пустая строка.

Comment: действительно, передается пустая строка... Можете подсказать как это исправить? Пытался сделать проверку           client.GetStringAsync("839219").IsCompleted, оно на не помогла

Comment: GetStringAsync ожидает адрес на вход, а не какой то Id.

Comment: можете показать как надо тогда передавать данные на основе моего кода?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, HAP : [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: На всякий случай сообщаю, что у Кинопоиска есть API.

Answer (score 2):

Сам нашел решение проблемы. Можно использовать как HtmlagillityPack, так и регулярку.

```
public void kinopoisk_time(string uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586";
    request.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*";

    var responseToString = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).ReadToEnd();

    string time = Regex.Match(responseToString, @"id=""runtime"">(.*)мин", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

    int tFilm = Convert.ToInt32(time);

    TimeSpan t = new TimeSpan(0, tFilm, 0);
    timeFilm.Text = t.ToString();
}
```